# app.less for linux

Tags: css, compiler-construction, less

Is there any program similar to app.less for linux? I want to keep comments that I have in the less files transferred the compiled css files. If not, is there a command line that I could use using the lessc command in linux?

The problem is that whenever I run the lessc command on my less files, I get a minified version css that throws away all my comments. I want the comments to help me debug as well as it being non-minified.

Answer (score 0):

Lessc compilers default is not to minify, but you can always check the commands help (lessc -h).

Also, in less you can use two types of comments the normal css style comments:

```
/* This is a CSS comment */
```

And these will be "printed" on the output css file.

The other style of comment is like single line comments in many languages:

```
// This is a LessCSS comment
```

And these do not get "printed" on the output css file.

Hope this helps!